Did Brian Jacques plan to write more books in the Castaways of the Flying Dutchman series?
As well as Brian Jacques's much better known Redwall series, he also wrote another series of books chronicling the adventures of a boy Ben and a dog Ned who travel the world as immortals after having escaped the cursed Flying Dutchman ship. There were three books published in this series during the author's lifetime:

Castaways of the Flying Dutchman (2001)
The Angel's Command (2003)
Voyage of Slaves (2006)

Jacques died in 2011. Is there any evidence as to whether he intended to continue with more books in this series, or if he considered it a complete trilogy? I always felt a lack of closure on the tale of Ben and Ned, especially after the third book with Serafina, but it's the sort of story that could continue indefinitely since the main characters are unaging - the existing books are set in a time period spanning centuries, so there could be arbitrarily many further books if the author so desired. Did he intend to leave that door open, or to leave us readers to imagine the further adventures of Ben and Ned ourselves?
